# How to fork lagom runAll

Tags: sbt, lagom

Since some dynamic compilation is used in my scala code, the [fork](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html) setting needs to be set to true during sbt testing and runtime.

I found that lagom provides the lagomForkedTestSettings parameter, but this parameter only works for test, but has no effect on runAll:

```
.settings(lagomForkedTestSettings: _ *)
```

At the same time, the following methods have also been tried:

```
.settings(fork := true)
.settings(fork in runAll := true)
```

Is there any way to pass the fork parameter to runAll?

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time. Lagom needs to run in process so that the devmode runtime can reload the app dynamically, pass it a new class loader to run from, etc. While in theory that interface could be made remote, there hasn't been enough demand to justify implementing it.